# Centering a flash widget

Tags: html, flash

I am trying to center a flash widget on this page http://www.gunauction.com/search/displayitem.cfm?ItemNum=10533886.

I have tried the `<center>` tag as well as  but it will still not center.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the flash widget *is* centered. The content within the flash widget is not, though.

You could reduce the width of the `<tr>`.

In general, though, flash embeds like that are not very pretty, nor are they recommended (i know that's all wix gives you to work with)

Comment: why are they not recommended?

Comment: why are they not recommended?

Comment: the use of flash for large portions of web content is limiting. It doesn't always follow accessibility standards and won't work on iOS devices (ipad and iphone). If that's what you're stuck with, though, than there's not much you can do.